# TextAngular is not functioning as expected?

Tags: angularjs

I just shifted from summernote to angularText. With summernote as my html editor everything was working as expected.

With angularText my editor shows fine, and the html previously entered (under summernote) looks fine. But there is a MAJOR issue!

**If I type a single key into the editor, all the html tags VANISH.**

One might imagine that I am missing something in the setup, but the initial display looks fine. It is only after I enter a key that things radically change.  In order to keep things simple I have in my scope:

```
$scope.html = "<p>Hello There</p>";
```

and the relevant markup is:

```
<div text-angular ng-model="html"></div>
<textarea ng-model="html" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
```

Before the key stroke I see:
[image: Before key stroke - expected view]

After the key stroke all the html tags are GONE!

[image: After key stroke - html tags GONE!]
You help is greatly appreciated!

PS: 'Dumb is really powerful!' and I am probably missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a directive: contenteditable that was causing havoc with textAngular.  I renamed my directive and the issue was immediately solved.

As it turns out I really need this contenteditable directive in other places!  The final solution as quite reasonable.  In my contenteditable directive, I simply tested for the class names for those contenteditible elements, and stopped the directive from modifying the html otherwise.  Hence I added within my contenteditable directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    ...
    ... 

    if (!element.hasClass('task_name')) {
      // don't affect any elements which don't have 'task_name' class
      // so don't bind or $render
    } 
    else 
    {
      ngModel.$render = function () {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
      };

      element.bind("blur keyup change", function () {
        // read is my magic needed for the task_name elements
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
    }

}
```